# How to set error div name in jQuery Validation plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery validation plugin.

I know how to wrap errors in a div, but I want to use different error classes for different forms(because of positioning).

Here is JavaScript how I wrap errors in a div:

```
    errorElement: "div",
    wrapper: "div",  // a wrapper around the error message
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    element.before(error);
    offset = element.offset();
    error.css('right', offset.right);
    }
```

and my css:

```
 div.error{
 ...some css styling
 }
```

**How I can set error div name ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly you want to use 'ErrorClass' to give the error a class to identify and style it.

Eg:

```
 $("#form").validate({
    errorClass: "error", //Defines error class as 'error'
    errorElement: "div",
    //etc...
});
```